# master page ruining pre_init

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, page-lifecycle

I have an aspx page which is (was) working fine

it consists of some simple controls in the aspx - which need their values setting dynamically
some user controls in the aspx which need some data passed to them
a couple of user controls that are being added dynamically via a repeater..
and some controls inside the usercontrols which need to be created dynamically

it was set up doing most of the work in the pre_init event - so that I could create the dynamic controls in both the page and the user controls so that they would hold onto their viewstates.

thus:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    paxID = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("g"))
    pax = New Pax(paxID)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlTitle.SelectedValue = pax.Title
        txtFirstname.Text = pax.FirstName
        txtSurname.Text = pax.Surname
        ddlGender.SelectedValue = pax.Gender.ToUpper()
        If (pax.DOB IsNot Nothing) Then
            txtDOB.Text = CType(pax.DOB, DateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        End If

        txtNationality.Text = pax.Nationality
        txtPassportNumber.Text = pax.PassportNumber

        If pax.Discount IsNot Nothing Then
            txtDiscount.Text = Math.Abs(pax.Discount.Price).ToString()
        End If
    End If
    LoadPaxData()
    RenderPageControls()

End Sub

Protected Sub RenderPageControls()

    ''work out how many weeks we are dealing with
    Dim weeks = Math.Floor(bk.nights / 7)
    If bk.nights Mod 7 <> 0 Then
        weeks += 1
    End If

    ''grab ALL the AVAILABILITY options for ALL weeks
    For ii = 1 To weeks
        Dim dt = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (ii - 1) * 7, theDate)
        allMHOptions.AddRange(AvailabilityOptionFactory.GetMainHolidayOptionAvailability(dt))
        allTravelOptions.AddRange(AvailabilityOptionFactory.GetTravelOptionAvailability(dt))
        allOptions.AddRange(AvailabilityOptionFactory.GetOptionAvailability(dt))
    Next

    allExtras = AvailabilityOptionFactory.GetExtrasAvailability(theDate)

    ''now all the booked options
    allBooked = Booked.BookedOptionFactory.LoadBookedOptions(pax.id)

    Dim tabContent = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    ''WEEK tabs
    For i = 1 To weeks
        tabContent.Add(String.Format(divIdFormat, i.ToString()), i)
    Next

    ''bind the repeaters with the week data
    rptULTabs.DataSource = tabContent
    rptULTabs.DataBind()
    rptTabs.DataSource = tabContent
    rptTabs.DataBind()

    ''EXTRAS tab
    ucExtras.extraOptions = allExtras
    ucExtras.alreadyBooked = allBooked

    ''SUPPLEMENTS tab
    ucSupplements.p = pax

    ''TRAVEL tab
    ucTravel.travelOptions = allTravelOptions
    ucTravel.alreadyBooked = Booked.BookedOptionFactory.LoadTravelOptions(pax.RecNum, Nothing)
    ucTravel.outboundWeekStart = theDate
    ucTravel.returnWeekStart = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (weeks - 1) * 7, theDate)
        ucTravel.returnDate = depDate
End Sub
```

loadpaxdetails loads some additional details onto the pax object

in RenderPageControls it grabs the bits for the usercontrols and these in turn may add some dynamic controls and set any data on those or any static controls in themselves..

aspx..

```
<div id="divTabs" runat="server">
    <ul id="ulTabs">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptULTabs">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a href="#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %>">Week
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value")%>
                </a></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <li><a href="#tabExtras">Extras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabRequirements">Requirements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabTravel">Travel</a></li>
    </ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTabs">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %>">
                <uc:WeekTab runat="server" ID="ucWeekTab" EnableViewState="true" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <div id="tabExtras">
        <uc:ExtrasTab runat="server" ID="ucExtras" EnableViewState="true" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabRequirements">
        <uc:SupplementsTab runat="server" ID="ucSupplements" EnableViewState="true" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabTravel">
        <uc:TravelTab runat="server" ID="ucTravel" EnableViewState="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

now this was all working fine until I decided i would like to put the aspx into a master page..

now what happens is that static controls in the aspx are not it seems created in time for the pre_init and thus it falls over when trying to set values on them.
along with this, i cannot add the user controls to the repeater either, as this is also not setup at this point

i am well aware that this is a life cycle problem, but dont understand how simply wrapping things in a master page can completely screw with all the events.. 
and I cant simply put the renderpagecontrols call in the page load, as this wont magically set the UC's back to the pre_init and hence get them using the viewstate..?

can anyone enlighten me please?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreInit` is not a good place for operations with controls, because at this stage not all controls are guaranteed to be initiated. In fact, they are not initiated when page has a master. This is because `PreInit` is the only place in the hole life-cycle where you can change master page dynamically, and of course tree of controls cannot be fully constructed by ASP.NET engine without master page being set.

The best advice for you here is to move your logic into `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` handlers. For instance, all properties set up and dynamic controls insertion (I assume that is what method `RenderPageControls` does) - in fact all you can call *initialization* should be placed in `Page_Init`. Data loading (presumably call of `LoadPaxData`) should be done within `Page_Load`. More info about what actions are recommended at what stage of page life cycle can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events).

However if you *badly* want to run all your code in `Page_PreInit` (although I can see no reason for that at the snippet) - there is a workaround. Insert the following line at the beginning of the handler:

```
MasterPage master = this.Master;
```

This will make the exception disappear. The reason why this trick works is that call to `Master` property triggers the creation of master page, which includes generation of content for all `asp:Content` controls. But still - this is just for general info, definitely not a recommended way to go.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply - i was using pre_init becuase on the msdn lifecycle page it says this about pre_init: the time to 'Create or re-create dynamic controls'. - as i understood it, so they could be hooked up with the viewstate.. is this in fact not true?

Comment: @nat, ViewState is loaded during the loading phase (check out the control's `LoadViewState` method), so this not a reason. I do not now for sure the ground for such a recommendation, but there is one reason I can think of: theme is applied after `PreInit`, so if you want your dynamic controls to use theme's skin, you have to create it and add it to control's tree at `PreInit`.